# responsive logo over image in carousel

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

i have here carousel working good using HTML BOOTSTRAP.. i wanted to add logo as small centered images over the carousel images and make them responsive on other devices, also i tried to add button under logo here and show centered as well... but in below code its not working as expected

```css
.carousel-caption {
    top: 20px !important;
    right: 20px !important;
}
.carousel-caption {
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 50% !important;
  /* left: 50% !important;
  transform: translate( -50%, -50%) !important; */
  text-align: center !important;
  color: white !important;
  margin: auto;
  font-weight: bold !important;
  max-width: 500px !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
}

.carousel-caption img {
  max-width: 150px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid main">

        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>

            </ol>

            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block w-300 " src="assets/images/dgWebsiteImages26.jpg" 
                        alt="First Image">

                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                         
                                <img class="" src="assets/images/logo---27.png" style="background-repeat: no-repeat;"
                        alt="First Image">
                        <a class="ripple rbutton" href="https://">A Button</a>
                      
                            
                        </div>

                </div>
        
            </div>
    
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div> 
    

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want? I made the VW logo a bit smaller to make it easier to see in the code snippet. Make sure that whenever you want to position an `position absolute` element within another element, that the parent of said `absolute` element has `position relative`. Also, the carousel-item was width: 100% even though the image wasn't, so after adding a `width: fit-content` it worked as expected. If you want to position it in one of the corners such as bottom, right change the following:

```
.carousel-caption {
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
}
```

```css
.carousel-item {
  position: relative;
  width: fit-content;
}

.carousel-caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate( -50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.carousel-caption-inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

button {
  width: 40px;
}

.carousel-caption img {
  max-width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid main">

  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100 " src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1504736038806-94bd1115084e?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&s=3d045bbf1ecc01c4c9ec011ce5c8977d" alt="First Image">

        <div class="carousel-caption d-md-block">
        <div class="carousel-caption-inner">
          <img class="" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1599305445671-ac291c95aaa9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1469&q=80" style="background-repeat: no-repeat;" alt="First Image">
          <button>test</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div> -->



</div>
```

Comment: If this is not what you had in mind let me know then I will look into it again

Comment: thank you ! for some reason it worked with out adding left: 50%; and
  transform: translate( -50%, -50%) !important; ... now i added a button which supposed to be under logo but it appears beside it in random way ... is there a way to show button beneath the logo centered?

Comment: I don't know if this is the most efficient way of doing this, but you can add a wrapper inside the `carousel-caption` and make it `display flex`, with `flex-direction column` and to center you can use`align-items center`